# Multiple lines concatenating into a single line in VS code for flask templates

Tags: flask, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code for web development and found this behavior annoying :

What I wanted to be in flask-templates is below

```
{{ render_field(form.email, placeholder=form.email.label.text) }}
{{ render_field(form.password, placeholder=form.password.label.text) }}
{{ render_field(form.textarea) }} 
{{ render_radio_fields(form.radios) }}
{{ render_field(form.selects) }}
```

But when I save this html file they are joining into a single line like below !

```
 {{ render_field(form.email, placeholder=form.email.label.text) }} {{ render_field(form.password, placeholder=form.password.label.text) }} {{ render_field(form.textarea) }} {{ render_radio_fields(form.radios) }} {{ render_field(form.selects) }}
```

Any help with this ? or Any settings need to be changed.

I cannot found any extensions in VS Code that support this.

Thanks

Comment: Check this example: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/wtforms/#forms-in-templates
you'll have to write a form helper and import it to your template

Comment: @ziiiro Thanks for response.But, what I need is the formatting issue in VS Code.

Comment: Sorry I understood the question wrong. I use VS Code and I don't have this problem, I'd suggest you disable the extensions you already installed and try again.

Comment: @RahulKodumuru have you find a solution yet? I have the exact same problem

Comment: @Olenka No, I haven't found any solution so far. I am using Pycharm lately.